# SQL Schedule Calendar

Tags: sql, calendar

It's possible to create on SQL, a query to schedule my IT Calendar?
I have this table:

```
IT Technician | Date
John          | 21-09-2014
Mark          | 20-09-2014
```

To control my IT Schedule I want a list of the schedule of my IT Guys.

```
           19-09-2014     20-09-2014     21-09-2014
John          Free           Free         Occupied
Mark          Free          Occupied        Free
Manuel        Free           Free           Free
Ricardo       Free           Free           Free
```

It's possible on a SQL Query?

Thank you in advance,
Tiago Januário

Comment: Yes it's possible, however syntax will depend on flavor of SQL (what RDBMS and version?).  if `PIVOT` is supported than yes.  otherwise a pivot equivalent would be needed. (MSFT Access would call it a cross tab query)

Answer (score 0):

you need to dynamic SQL using PIVOT

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
set @cols = ( STUFF( ( select ',[' + Date + ']' from Table1 
                       for xml path ('')),1,1,''))

set @query = 'select  '+ @cols +' FROM 
(select *  from Table1 )T
pivot
( max([IT Technician]) for Date in ( ' + @cols + ')
)p'


exec sp_executesql @query
```